# How are agents in multi-agent systems parsing messages and making decisions

Tags: system, multi-agent

I have a question on theory of multi-agent systems. The question is about how do agents understand messages sended by other agents. What algorithms or methods can be used to parse text in messages?
How do agent decide what acrion should be done when it has read message?
I have read tons of articles about multi-agent systems, but no one of them discusses the matter of parsing messages and making decisions based on what they read.
Probably someone would be so kind and share with me some information, examples about that.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered in the form used on this site.  There are many different frameworks, languages, and protocols used by many different multi-agent systems.  The [FIPA](http://www.fipa.org/) organisation is producing standards, aimed at consolidating MAS software technologies.  You could have a look there and see what they're working with.

Comment: @MikeofSST, I don't need frameworks or languages. I should wright it on my own, but I dont have enough information. I already looked at FIPA documentation and as I said, I didnt find those part of FIPA wich pay attention to process of parsing dialog itself and  making decisions. Can you recommend some right forums for such questions?

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of message you want to parse and what language you'd like to write the parser in?

Comment: @MikeofSST , thank u for answering! I would like to parse messages, written in KQML notation and parser in C# language, but if u know theory for this topic(or open examples of parsers on other languages) and can give me links, it would be great too!